# Бот не реагирует на кнопку

Tags: python, telebot

После перехода в функцию def eagle, бот не реагирует на выбор кнопки.
Может я что то забыл, подскажите пожалуйста

```
elif message.text == "Орел или Решка":
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Орел")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Решка")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")
    markup.row(btn1, btn2)
    markup.row(btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите  -  Орел или Решка!", reply_markup=markup)
    eagle(message)



def eagle(message):
    list = ["Орел", "Решка"]
    if message.text == "Орел":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Противник выберает Решка")
    elif message.text == "Решка":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Противник выбирает Орел")
    if message.text in list:
        pc_vrag = random.choice(list)
        if message.text == "Орел" and pc_vrag == "Орел":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы победили!")
        elif message.text == "Решка" and pc_vrag == "Решка":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы победили!")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы проиграли!")
```

Comment: используйте `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` для обработки ответов с `ReplyMarkup`